# What is Fermi Surface of superconductors?

Tags: solid-state-physics, superconductivity, spectroscopy, fermi-energy

It is known that, in superconductors, at the Fermi level, electrons are paired(Cooper pairs) and there is a gap (see figure).

[image]
 However, there are lots of [ARPES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle-resolved_photoemission_spectroscopy) experiments showing the "Fermi surface" of superconductors.

My question is >> How does ARPES show the  Fermi surface if there are no electrons at the Fermi level?

Comment: The Fermi surface is the set of highest-energy occupied states. Whether that is at the Fermi energy or not depends on the band structure as you have noted. ARPES measures the electrons, not the Fermi energy.

Comment: I know this is old but I am going to point out ARPES can be related to the spectral function: A(k,w). One typically finds A(k,w=0) is the Fermi surface (number of gapless excitations connected to the ground state with momentum k), but there are exceptions. The answer to the question is there is no Fermi surface! There was an instability.